# Generate grouped checkboxes JQuery mobile with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Please check this code: http://jsfiddle.net/Hce8y/

I'm trying to generate a list of grouped check boxes:

```
function ItemCode_Changed(sender, onload) {
$('#category-contianer-id-3').append(
        '<div data-role="fieldcontain">'
             + '<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">'
                + '<legend>Choose as many:</legend>'
                + '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1a" id="checkbox-1a" class="custom" />'
                + '<label for="checkbox-1a">Cheetos</label>'
                + '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2a" id="checkbox-2a" class="custom" />'
                + '<label for="checkbox-2a">Doritos</label>'                    
                + '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-3a" id="checkbox-3a" class="custom" />'
                + '<label for="checkbox-3a">Fritos</label>'
                + '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-4a" id="checkbox-4a" class="custom" />'
                + '<label for="checkbox-4a">Sun Chips</label>'
            + '</fieldset>'
        + '</div>');

$('#category-contianer-id-3 [data-role="fieldcontain"]').fieldcontain();
    $('#category-contianer-id-3 [data-role="fieldcontain"]').fieldcontain('refresh');

    $("#category-contianer-id-3 input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio();
$("#category-contianer-id-3 input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio('refresh');
//$('#my-home').page();
```

}

when change the text in the input, but the result doesn't looks like the demo.

Is there any mistakes, any help are appreciated.

Comment: "result doesn't looks like the demo" ... what demo?

Comment: Demo on Jquery mobile [website](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/checkboxes/) there is no corners for checkboxes in the middle only the last and first one

Comment: Is there a reason why you use the onchange event? I would rather use keyup and possibly filter the current result of the input field to see if we can already proceed. This will immediatly show results when the users is typing and does not force him to click outside first to let changes take effect. In fact I had to figure that out in your example. I wasn't able to generate the list at first :)

Comment: @Zim84 after comeback to my example i faced that two :), but actually i don't use this event in my application i generate the list in javascript method by call Ajax when user select from combo box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call both methods:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').checkboxradio();
$('fieldset').controlgroup();
```

Calling fieldcontain() after changing its child-elements doesn't change anything. At least I was not able to see any differences.

Answer (score 0):

Hey why don't you already put the code up in the HTML and when the user clicks on the 'Append Stuff' button, the div shows up?

```
<div id="category-contianer-id-3" style="display:none">
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>Choose as many:</legend>
        <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox-1a' id='checkbox-1a' class='custom' />
        <label for='checkbox-1a'>Cheetos</label>
       <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox-2a' id='checkbox-2a' class='custom' />
        <label for='checkbox-2a'>Doritos</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

and show it with:

```
 $('#category-contianer-id-3').show();
```

Check out the demo I've created, maybe that'll help you.
http://jsfiddle.net/ZaZSa/1/

Comment: Thanks for your replay but i should load the list using Javascript because i get the options according to some input values and then go to server using Json after that build the list

Comment: Complex problem, I can't seem to figure it out.